# Which library of java should be used to prepare Face Detection Application

Tags: java, vs-web-application-project

Which library should be used in java for preparing application of face detection.
for example 
java.util
java.lang

i would like to know that for face detection application which library should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

[OpenCV library which focuses on real time image processing](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-12-opencv-face-detection-for-java-developers)

or

[Face Detection in Java - Haar Cascade with JJIL](http://www.richardnichols.net/2011/01/java-facial-recognition-haar-cascade-with-jjil-guide/)